# Spring MVC 3.0 issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Use Spring MVC along(without Spring), 
web.xml mapping

```
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Spring MVC config file: springmvc-servlet.xml

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
      <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
      <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

<mvc:annotation-driven />    
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

Why Spring MVC handle all requests, including static file like index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure of what the question is but the spring source documentation provides clear usage of the default-servlet-handler and below I have added the extract and link:

> This tag allows for mapping the DispatcherServlet to "/" (thus
>   overriding the mapping of the container's default Servlet), while
>   still allowing static resource requests to be handled by the
>   container's default Servlet. It configures a
>   DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler with a URL mapping of "/**" and the
>   lowest priority relative to other URL mappings.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Comment: <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> change to <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As we know Spring MVC is Categorised in Model, View and controller,Each module is Sepated From Each Other and To Integrate them the controller manage them and all configuration is in web.xml file.

Hence All Requst and Responses handle By Spring MVC.

Thats All

Answer (score 0):

Usually **DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping** and **AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter** are the controllers which takes care of all the default [Spring MVC Requests](http://www.javainterviewpoint.com/spring-mvc-simpleurlhandlermapping-example/).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.